# How do I add custom text via the input box

Tags: excel, vba, user-input

I'm using the following code to prompt the user for a variable and add that to each row at the end. For some reason, the number in the last line is the number that fills all the cells. Is there a way to fix this code?

```
Dim lr As Long    
Dim myRange As Integer

myRange = Application.InputBox("Enter Item Number", Type:=1)

lr = Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Range("O2:O" & lr).Value = Format(myRange, "1")
```

Comment: what is the `Format(myRange, "1")` supposed to do? `"1"` is not a valid number format https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fb56f4y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I realize this. This is the problem I'm trying to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your range from `O2` to `O" & lr`.

> Range("O" & lr).Value = Format(myRange, "1")

Or

> Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Format(myRange, "1")

Comment: The current code works, but I'm sure the "1" should be something else because that is the number that fills all the cells.

Comment: I didn't understand why you had the 1 as a format parameter.  I figured one problem at a time

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you use Format but..

If you want to Format it to be sure it's a numeric format I think the best way is loop on your inputbox While not isnumeric(myrange) or empty value.

to format a Number with format i think it's a Zero..

`Format(1 , "0000")` Should give 0001
`Format(10, "0")` Should give 10